# Error booting GhostBSD in VirtualBox after trying to get sound to work

Tags: boot, freebsd

> Boot: F1
>
> /boot/config: device sound
> device snd_hda
> device snd_sbc
> device snd_sb16
>
> FreeBSD/x86 boot
> Default: 0:ad(0,a)snd_sb16
> bootL Bi sbd)sb16
> FreeBSD/x86 boot
> Default: 0:ad(0,a)snd_sb16
> boot:

What do I type into boot?

Edit:
The files I modified are /boot/config, /boot/loader.conf, and /boot/device.hints. I don't know if I modified /boot/defaults/loader.conf.
What's the location of the FreeBSD kernel?

Comment: What files did you modify to fix sound?

Comment: /boot/config, /boot/loader.conf, and /boot/device.hints. I don't know if I modified /boot/defaults/loader.conf.

Comment: You may want to post this question on the [freebsd-questions](https://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-questions) mailing list. You'll get much more attention.